# How Do I Update TextView Result On App Launch

Tags: java, android

I am pulling data from a Website to my application. I want the TextView to display the result I want from the website immediately as the user launches the app. However html codes make the result look weird some times and I am trying to correct it. I have the codes that will do what I am trying to do. I just can't figure out how to get it to do everything automatically at app launch. It needs to pull the code from the website and if it receives any special symbols within the string I want it to correct it as soon as the app launches. Here is an example...

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewbyId(R.id.my_textview_result);
tv.setText(resultFromWebsite);
```

The result it pulled: You u0026 Me Forever!

The result I want: You & Me Forever! My app should correct that.

Here is my correction code...

```
public void symbolTextFilter(TextView myTv) {
String getData = tv.getText().toString();

if (getData.contains("u0026") {
   String replace = getData.replace("u0026", "&");
   myTv.setText(replace);
}
```

Now on my onCreate Method

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewbyId(R.id.my_textview_result);
tv.setText(resultFromWebsite);

symbolTextFilter(tv);
```

It will not make that correction. It will if I put the symbolTextFilter(tv) in a onClickListener button though. I don't want to assign the correction in a button. I want it automatically. My guess is, everything that I have in the onCreate is happening too fast for corrections to be made. How do I fix that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "The result it pulled: You u0026 Me Forever!" -- that is probably not what you actually received. You probably received `You \u0026 Me Forever!`, as `\u0026` represents `&` in Unicode. "How do I fix that?" -- have `symbolTextFilter()` work on strings, not `TextViews`. Then call `tv.setText(symbolTextFilter(resultFromWebsite))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tv.setText(symbolTextFilter(resultFromWebsite))
```

You should use the method symbolTextFilter to handle the string only:

```
public void symbolTextFilter(String input) {
if (input.contains("u0026") {
   return input.replace("u0026", "&");
} else {
   return input 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to change public void to public String for it to work. However, I have a new problem. The result now displays You \& Me Forever! How do I get rid of "\"?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I got it! I'm not sure where the "\" came from because it wasn't in the original string that it pulled before the correction. I fixed it with this...

```
public String symbolTextFilter(String input) {
if (input.contains("u0026") {
return input.replace("\\" + "u0026", "&");
} else {
return input 
}
```